# Relations in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

**Dish.php**

```
class Dish extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'name', 'description',  'enable'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function components()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\DishValues', 'App\Dish', 'id', 'dishes_id');
    }
}
```

**DishValues**

```
class DishValues extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['dishes_id', 'food_ingredient_id', 'quantity'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ingredient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\FoodIngredient', 'food_ingredient_id');
    }
}
```

**FoodIngredient.php**

```
class FoodIngredient extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    public function scopeVisibleDemo($query)
    {
        return $query->where('available_in_demo', 1);
    }

    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'name', 'garbage', 'energy_value', 'protein', 'fat', 'available_carbohydrates', 'roughage', 'description', 'url_address', 'allergen', 'available_in_demo', 'enable'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I get my data:

```
Dish::with('components')->paginate(25);
```

How can I get in this code values from FoodIngredient?

This is not working:

```
Dish::with('components, ingredient')->paginate(25);
```

or

```
Dish::with('components')->with('ingredient')->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have multiple relationships, you use `:with()` with an array of values, not a comma separated string.

This example comes from the [docs on "Eager Loading Multiple Relationships"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) and I've re-named the models based on your example

```php
App\Dish::with(['components', 'ingredient'])->get();
```

There is also a good blog post that explores the [eager/lazy loading of related models](https://medium.com/@sdkcodes/laravel-eloquent-eager-loading-9596b15e8b5d) in this way.

Comment: it's not working. I have error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dishes_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `dishes` where `dishes_id` = 2)

Comment: Double check your schema (migrations) and model/relationships as per [Has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) in the laravel docs. This suggests your foreign key's might not be setup or declared correctly in either your model or migration.